# .clang-format BlockIndent doesn't work with curly brackets

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

I'm currently setting up a `.clang-format` file for our code repository. However, I'm a stuck with getting `AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent` to work with constructor calls using curly brackets (`Cpp11BracedListStyle` is set to `true`).

If I use regular brackets everything is working fine:

```
ObjectWithLongName var(
    some,
    constructor,
    call,
    with,
    many,
    arguments
);
```

Now if I use curly brackets instead, I'm ending having the closing bracket on the same line as the last agrument:

```
ObjectWithLongName var{
    some,
    constructor,
    call,
    with,
    many,
    arguments};
```

I went through the entire [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#) but didn't find a particular parameter for this. What setting am I missing?

---

Whole `.clang-format` file:

```
Language:        Cpp
# BasedOnStyle:  LLVM
AccessModifierOffset: -2
AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent
AlignConsecutiveMacros: false
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: AcrossComments
AlignConsecutiveBitFields: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Right
AlignOperands:   Align
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: true
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Empty
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: MultiLine
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel:  false
  AfterClass:      false
  AfterControlStatement: Never
  AfterEnum:       false
  AfterFunction:   false
  AfterNamespace:  false
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  AfterStruct:     false
  AfterUnion:      false
  AfterExternBlock: false
  BeforeCatch:     true
  BeforeElse:      true
  BeforeLambdaBody: false
  BeforeWhile:     false
  IndentBraces:    false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
  SplitEmptyRecord: false
  SplitEmptyNamespace: false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: NonAssignment
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: false
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeColon
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: true
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeColon
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit:     50  # Reduced value for testing
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DeriveLineEnding: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat:   false
EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: LogicalBlock
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IncludeBlocks:   Preserve
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^"(llvm|llvm-c|clang|clang-c)/'
    Priority:        2
    SortPriority:    0
  - Regex:           '^(<|"(gtest|gmock|isl|json)/)'
    Priority:        3
    SortPriority:    0
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        1
    SortPriority:    0
IncludeIsMainRegex: '(Test)?$'
IncludeIsMainSourceRegex: ''
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentCaseBlocks: false
IndentGotoLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentExternBlock: AfterExternBlock
IndentWidth:     4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
InsertTrailingCommas: None
InsertBraces: true
InsertNewlineAtEOF: true
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true
LambdaBodyIndentation: OuterScope
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 2
NamespaceIndentation: None
ObjCBinPackProtocolList: Auto
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 2
ObjCBreakBeforeNestedBlockParam: true
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PackConstructorInitializers: Never
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 10
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
PointerAlignment: Left
ReferenceAlignment: Left
ReflowComments:  true
SortIncludes:    true
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCaseColon: false
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: false
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpacesInConditionalStatement: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
BitFieldColonSpacing: Both
Standard:        Latest
StatementAttributeLikeMacros: [emit]
StatementMacros:
  - Q_UNUSED
  - QT_REQUIRE_VERSION
TabWidth:        8
UseCRLF:         false
UseTab:          Never
WhitespaceSensitiveMacros:
  - STRINGIZE
  - PP_STRINGIZE
  - BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE
...
```

Comment: It seems this is actually a bug in clang itself (see https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/55485).